# How to set the right position in xib

Tags: ios, xib

[image: the xib]

[image: the simulator]

I am new to ios. I was confused that why my simulator shows defferent with my xib?

Comment: It looks like your Storyboard or xib is using the iPhone 4” resolution and the simulator is using the iPhone 3.5” resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Auto Layout, with a simulated iPhone 5 display (4" Retina) but then running it on the 3.5" simulator. The bottom-most UI element has a constraint fixing its distance to the bottom of the window, so when the window shrinks, it moves "up" relative to the other elements. Try switching the simulated view to a 3.5" screen in your Storyboard, there's a button for that in the bottom right of the Storyboard in Xcode.